# nginx upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream fixed by server restart

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx

We are running nginx as a front end proxy server, back to our api servers.

Nginx proxies traffic to an Amazon application load balancer (ALB) which has three plus servers attached to it.  Here are the applicable parts of our nginx.conf:

```
sendfile            on;
tcp_nopush          on;
tcp_nodelay         on;
client_header_timeout 30;
client_body_timeout 30;
client_max_body_size 350M;
gzip on;
gzip_vary on;
gzip_comp_level 2;
gzip_buffers 4 8k;
gzip_min_length 1024;
gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
gzip_types text/plain application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml text/css application/json;
gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";
client_body_buffer_size  500k;
client_header_buffer_size 64k;
large_client_header_buffers 4 64k;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
keepalive_timeout 30;
keepalive_requests 1024;
proxy_connect_timeout 300;
proxy_read_timeout    300;
proxy_send_timeout    300;


server {
    listen       8888 default_server;
    server_name  _;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
    index   index.html;

    location /api/ {
                    proxy_pass         http://internal-ALB:8080/api/;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header   Access-Control-Allow-Origin $http_origin;
    }

}
```

Periodically we will get a server slowdown, and the site will eventually go down.  We will see the following errors in the logs:

```
upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream
```

However, when we look at all of the upstream components they are working.  The ALB is working, and all targets are healthy.  The individual servers are up and healthy.  It appears that "something happened" causing it to break, but whatever that event was it was resolved.  However, after the resolution the proxy connections were not reset, still resulting in timeouts.

We can resolve the issue by restarting nginx,  However, we want nginx to reset the proxy connection on it's own without restarting the server.

Based on our setup, we are having a very difficult problem replicating this issue, because it may be AWS related.  However, we would like our system to be fault tolerant and resolve this issue without restarting the server.

thanks.
myles.

Comment: did you got any solution for this issue?

Comment: Were you able to find any solutions?

Comment: This might be helpful https://serverfault.com/questions/811904/aws-ec2-ubuntu-upstream-timed-out-110-connection-timed-out-while-reading-re